# karaf (fuse) Unresolved constraint in bundle missing requirement osgi.wiring.package

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I am trying to install a bundle which depends on another.

When I attempt to install it via maven (where it is stored), I get the following error:

```
install -s mvn:com.mycompany.er/ER_api/0.1218.0
Bundle ID: 544
Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
    Unable to start bundle mvn:com.mycompany.er/ER_api/0.1218.0: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.mycompany.er.ER_api [544]: 
    Unable to resolve 544.0: missing requirement [544.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.mycompany.application.errors)(version>=0.145.0)(!(version>=1.0.0)))
```

The bundle shows up as installed:

```
[ 544] [Installed  ] [            ] [       ] [   60] ER_api (0.1218.0)
```

Listing the headers for the `ER_api` bundle show that it does indeed depend on `com.mycompany.application.errors`, and that shows up in red.

```
Import-Package = 
....
com.mycompany.application.errors;version="[0.145,1)",
```

According to my understanding the version required is greater than or equal to 0.145, but less than 1.  So version 0.145.0 should meet this criteria.

The package in question `com.mycompany.application.errors` is available in the bundle `APPLICATION_app_common`, which appears to be installed and active:

```
[ 540] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] APPLICATION_app_common (0.145.0)
```

Checking whether the package is exported shows that it is:

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> headers 540
APPLICATION_app_common (540)
----------------------------
Manifest-Version = 1.0
Bnd-LastModified = 1459506884903    
Tool = Bnd-1.50.0
....
Export-Package = 
com.mycompany.application;version=0.145.0,
com.mycompany.application.errors;
    uses:="javax.xml.bind.annotation,
        javax.ws.rs.core,
        com.mycompany.application.smapi";
    version=0.145.0,
```

The only thing that complicates matters is that it's not a direct dependency, it's a transitive dependency.  `ER_api` depends on `ER_transactions_log`, which depends on `APPLICATION_app_common`.  I have the latest version of `ER_transactions_log` installed and active:

```
[ 511] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] ER_transactions_log (0.45.0.SNAPSHOT)
```

I can't understand why it can't see the exported package.  `APPLICATION_app_common` clearly lists the package in its Export-Package list.

How do I debug this?

Comment: CAn we see `headers 544` for your ER_api bundle? Are you importing a different version of javax.xml.bind or javax.ws.rs.core or com.mycompany.application.smapi?
And it is not a transitive dependency, since it is declared in your import packages. Could you maybe fine tune your imports?